# How to mock services for integration tests in Flutter

Tags: flutter, testing, mocking, integration-testing

I learn how to make integration test in flutter. But there is one concept I don't understand :

Here a simple test :

```
@GenerateMocks([Authentication])
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('Test display error when email and password are empty', (tester) async {
    final mockAuthentication = MockAuthentication();
    when(mockAuthentication
      .tokenHasExpired())
      .thenAnswer((_) async => true);

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      ProviderScope(child: MaterialApp(home:  MyApp()))
    );

    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(milliseconds: 5000));

    await tester.tap(find.byType(ElevatedButton));
    await tester.pump();

    expect(find.text('Email address is empty'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('Password is empty'), findsOneWidget);
 });
}
```

As you can see, I try to mock my Authentication service (I'm using mockito) but how can I say to my app "Use this mock instead of the real service" ? Because obviously with this code the real service is still used.

Thx